# How to make this nodejs lambda wait until the job is done?

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda

I'm a newbie in nodejs.

I have an AWS lambda that reads a queue and delete messages after processing them:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.logger = console;
const sqs = new AWS.SQS({apiVersion: '2012-11-05'});
const redriveQueueUrl = 'https://myqueue";

async function deleteMessage (messageToDelete) {
    let params = {
        QueueUrl: redriveQueueUrl,
        ReceiptHandle: messageToDelete.ReceiptHandle
    };
    sqs.deleteMessage(params, function (err, data) {
        if (err) console.log(err, err.stack);
        else console.log(data);
    });
}


exports.handler = async (event) => {

    var params = {
        QueueUrl: redriveQueueUrl,
        MaxNumberOfMessages: '2',

    };
    let sqsResponse = await sqs.receiveMessage(params).promise();
    let messages = sqsResponse.Messages

    for (let index in messages) {
        // do something here later.
        await deleteMessage(messages[index]);
    };

    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify('End of Lambda!'),
    };
    return response;
};
```

This code correctly reads a given queue but does not delete any message.
How can fix this problem?

Comment: I asume that your `sqs.deleteMessage` function is also asynchronous, but you have not placed `await` before it. Thus it will just run without waiting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sqs.deleteMessage` needs to return a promise. Otherwise calling `await sqs.deleteMessage()` will return immediately.

Try this:

```
async function deleteMessage (messageToDelete) {
    let params = {
        QueueUrl: redriveQueueUrl,
        ReceiptHandle: messageToDelete.ReceiptHandle
    };
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
      sqs.deleteMessage(params, function (err, data) {
          if (err) return reject(err);
          else return resolve(data);
      });
    })
}
```